# How to shuffle a FilteredList in java?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

When I want to shuffle an `FilteredList` I get a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.

How to handle this?

Code:

```
FilteredList<Card> filteredData = 
    new FilteredList(ob, filterByOption(option.get("selectedCard"), option.get("chapter")));

if (option.get("cardOrder") == "shuffle") {
    filterCards=filteredData;
    FXCollections.shuffle(filterCards);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html#FilteredList-javafx.collections.ObservableList-):

> **Wraps an ObservableList** and filters it's content using the provided
>   Predicate. **All changes in the ObservableList are propagated
>   immediately to the FilteredList.**

Therefore, you can shuffle the underlying source `ObservableList` instead:

```
FXCollections.shuffle(ob);
```

**Example:**

```
ObservableList<String> obsList = 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList("Amanda", "Bill", "Adam", "Albus", "Cicero");
FilteredList<String> fList = new FilteredList<>(obsList, s -> s.startsWith("A"));

System.out.println(fList);
FXCollections.shuffle(obsList);
System.out.println(fList);
```

*Output:*

```
[Amanda, Adam, Albus]
[Adam, Albus, Amanda]
```